# How to infuse starch into potato?

Tags: potatoes, starch, chips

So, I dont have Russet potatoes, which seem to be the holy grail for making potato chips. However, I noticed that they are chosen for their high quantity of starch (and form), so i want way to infuse starch into potato.

Answer (score 19):

You can't infuse starch into a potato. A potato is not a sponge, and even if it were, infused starch wouldn't work. You need not just some amount of starch, you need the proper kind of starch, in the proper "packaging", in its proper place within the closed potato cell.

So it's wrong to state that a given potato cultivar is chosen for a recipe because of the *amount* of starch it has; rather, it's chosen for its "starch profile" which encompasses many other variables related to starch than simply the amount.

At the same time, there are several hundreds of potato cultivars in the world. It seems that the US market is dominated by 3-4 of them, and so recipe writers in the English speaking world tend to declare one of them "perfect" for a given usage, simply because when you only have three or four quite distinct choices, one of them will easily become the preferred one. So, "russet potatoes are the holy grail for chip making" actually means "if I make chips with the other three varieties available to me, I get a taste and texture that's distinctly different from russet, and I have a strong preference for the russet one".

So, if you want to make very good chips and don't have access to russets, all you have to do is to figure out *which potato you have access to gives you good chips*. If your results are similar to, or better than, russet, that's all there is to it. If you don't have access to any good chip-making cultivar, or if your taste preference is tightly bound to russet chips only, your only option is to gain access to other cultivars. But you can't turn a given potato into something else.

Comment: FWIW, Red Bliss, Yukon Gold, and several other varieties make excellent chips.  IMHO, better than Russets.

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered just using a different potato?
In the UK we don't see russets at all; our crisps [chips] are not made from them ever… though we don't know what type they **are** made from - it seems no-one wants to tell us. Walker's [the UK's largest brand] uses 'potatoes controlled by PepsiCo' and that's as much as they're saying. The other brands seem equally reticent.

The Guardian newspaper is often good for 'investigative cookery' - testing many different way to make a single thing. They did one on potato crisps & arrived at 5 potato types suitable, but one clear winner.
Maris piper, with king edward, arran victorie, rooster or the purple violetta as runners-up.

Their article is well worth a read - [How to cook the perfect crisps](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2016/apr/28/how-to-cook-the-perfect-crisps)

Comment: Turns out there's a [quite convoluted](https://scroll.in/article/1033021/explained-the-legal-battle-over-the-potatoes-used-to-make-lays-chips) international patent system for potato cultivars, where the big brands use their proprietary varieties.  Frito-Lays use(d) a [patented](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20050081269A1/en) variety called FL-2027 although, since the patent has expired, maybe they have a [new one](https://patents.google.com/patent/US10561114B1/) now.

Comment: so floury potatoes then.

Comment: @WendyG yes, russets are pretty much the only floury potatoes available in the US, but I'd imagine any floury potatoes would work similarly.